# What is the best way to implement multiple logs location using log4j?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have to implement multiple log location using log4j in out project which includes multiple modules, for each module i have to log the in separate location

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the log4j.properties on this articles would help you seek what you are looking for.  http://ta.cnci.org/more-about-java/35-java-blogs/238-dailyfileappender and may be you could use the DailyFileAppender.java that I wrote a while back. 
The idea is simple and it is in 4 parts:

1. Set the log4j.rootCategory to include your "FILE DEF"
2. Define your "FILE DEF" such as log4j.appender.SOADAILY
3. Tell the Logger to filter it to your "FILE DEF" as: log4j.logger.com.incresearch.soa.db=DEBUG, TDLDAILY
4. Tell the Logger not delete from everywhere else as:     log4j.additivity.org.cnci.tdl=false

But here is an example:

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  Default log4j.properties file.  This should be in the LocalFiles folder
    #
    #    Possible Log Levels:
    #      FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG
    #
    log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, SOADAILY, TDLDAILY
    log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  The following properties configure the Daily Rolling File appender.
    #  For SOA components, mostly from org.cnci.soa.* packages
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY = org.cnci.util.DailyFileAppender
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.File = logs/SOAServices.log
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.MaxLogs = 30
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.Append = true
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.SOADAILY.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  The following properties configure the Daily Rolling File appender for TDL.
    #  For TDL applications, mostly from org.cnci.tdl.* packages and jboss seams, richfaces...
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.File = logs/TDLServices.log
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.MaxLogs = 30
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.Append = true
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.TDLDAILY.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


    # Extracting all Adapter logging into it own file
    log4j.logger.org.cnci.soa=DEBUG, SOADAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.cnci.soa=false
    log4j.logger.com.hazelcast=ERROR, SOADAILY
    log4j.additivity.com.hazelcast=false
    log4j.logger.org.opensaml=ERROR, SOADAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.opensaml=false

    # Extracting all DB (TDL) logging into it own file 
    log4j.logger.com.incresearch.soa.db=DEBUG, TDLDAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.cnci.tdl=false
    log4j.logger.org.jboss.seam=ERROR, DAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.jboss.seam=false
    log4j.logger.org.richfaces=ERROR, DAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.richfaces=false
    log4j.logger.org.ajax4jsf=ERROR, DAILY
    log4j.additivity.org.ajax4jsf=false
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion...but,i want to implement different log locations for different module...its only helpful in creating new log locations in when the current size of log exceeds...i am not interested in creating new with same log name but....selecting different log locations...from single class

Comment: Use a RollingFileAppender and see what that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here: [Log4j to write json array to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290497/log4j-to-write-json-array-to-disk/22290784)

It shows how to send com.foo.bar logs to console, com.example to a file appender; you can mix and match - essentially the package name after the log4j.com. part will create a new logger for the sub tree of classes rooted there; if in a descendant package you need the change the location (remember, appenders are additive by default) you'll have to set 'inherit' to 'false'.

Comment: thak you                                                                          it's not like that, Actually  I have to implment logs which are logging into the multiple log files, based on the different application using the single logging configuration by dynamically selecting the log files. using a single logging class