# Log4j to write json array to disk

Tags: java, logging, log4j, filewriter

Im creating a log file system. the log file will be in json format so a server can read it after but i dont think thats too important.  What i need to know is can log4j be configured to write into to a file but without any tags like info,debug, timestamp etc in the file.  I have looked here

but this polutes the file with with other things. I want ONLY the data i write to show up in the file.  I'd also like to set some kind of file rotation on the file if it gets too big after a max size is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy, using a `log4j.properties` configuration file (place it at the top of your classpath, and Log4j will 'just find it'):

```
# This is the default logger, simply logs to console
log4j.logger.com.foo.bar=DEBUG,A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Note the Pattern here, emits a lot of stuff - btw, don't use this in production
# %C is expensive - see the Javadoc for ConversionPattern for the meaning of all
# the % modifiers:
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd, HH:mm:ss} [%C{2}] %-5p - %m%n

# Logging to file can be enabled by using this one
log4j.logger.com.example=DEBUG, R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/var/log/generic.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

# This is the most minimalist layout you can have: just the 'm'essage is emitted
# (and a \n newline):
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

All the classes in the `com.foo.bar` package (and subpackages) will log to console, those in `com.example` (and below) will log to `/var/log/generic.log`.

To emit JSON, just use `Jackson` (`com.fasterxml`) convert your data to a JSON object and write it out as a string.

Comment: thanks. can you tell me what this line means:# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1   lets say i change that to 3.  does that mean that i'll have files generic1.log , generic2.log and generic3.log ???

Comment: You're welcome. Essentially yes: I think the naming will be more like generic.1.log etc (easier to parse/handle with globs)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) with %m%n only, and combine with the answer to previously asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032446/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-multiple-logs-location-usign-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a custom log appender, I have a vague recollection of there being an example to do this with MongoDB.
MongoDD stores its data as JSON, so it have converted the log to json format before inserting it.

I would start by searching for a MondgoDB appender, and looking at the file appender that is shipped, that should give you a starting point for an appender if one doesnt already exist.

http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Home